# How to pass javascript variable to gsp tag

Tags: javascript, grails

```
<script>
   var numx = 5000;
   alert('${myCustomTagLib(number:"numx")}')
</script>
```

How to pass javascript varable "numx" to gsp tag?

Answer (score 5):

You clearly needs to understand, when GSP is executed and when JavaScript is executed.

Execution of GSP happens in the server. At this point, there is no JavaScript variable to assign. So your "numx" in always null, when "myCustomTagLib" is called.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do like that way but you can do it with ajax

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/someController",
   data: { number: numx } // here  send the data to your controller and process it
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    // display the processed data here
    alert(  msg );
});
```